Color of sealant between driveway concrete slabs
There are some gaps between our driveway concrete slabs that have widened some over the years. I had someone come and "seal" the gaps but they used a color (very bright white) that looks terrible.  Called Home Depot and asked about this and they said the seal only comes in that color.  Looking for advice on next steps and how to fix.

Paint it the color of your concrete.

I've never seen concrete sealant that was bright white...are you sure they used the right product?
